# How to update $('select').material_select(); after $http complete

Tags: angularjs, select, materialize, angular-http

I am using angular and materializecss ([link](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select-initialization)). I want after $http complete update `material_select()` but unable find any solution.

I have tried so far::

```
1> $('select').material_select();

2> $(element).material_select();
```

Can anyone suggest any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which $http call are you talking about?

Comment: I am calling an `ajax` through angular AND on `.success` I am using that initializing function.

Comment: Did you call material_select() in the .success of your $http call?

Comment: yes, but how to call I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following steps to solve your answer::

```
 $http({
  method: "POST",
  url: '/xxxxxxx',
  data: {
   type: "1"
  }
 })
  .success(function (result) {
   //result-> [{value:1,name:val1},{}...]
   $scope.choices = result;

  //timeout use for resolving $digest issue of $scope
   $timeout(function () {
    angular.element(document).find('#mySelect').material_select();
   }, 500);

  });
```

`$timeout` use this service in your controller.

IN your DOM it will be as below

```
<select class="" id="mySelect" material-select ng-model="accountType" ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in choices">
</select>
```

Comment: I'm ok with the selector, but why do to use a timeout?